# footer_links static block not working magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, static-block

i'm working with magento 1.9.0.1 with b-responsive theme.there are two static blocks in my backend inside CMS (1) footer_links (2)footer_links_company.
inside my app\design\frontend\b-responsive\enterprise\template\page\html\footer.phtml its is called as:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links') ?>
```

and here is the content inside that static block:

```
<ul id="Footer">
<li><a href="{{store direct_url="about-magento-demo-store"}}">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store direct_url="customer-service"}}">Customer Service</a></li>
<li class="last privacy"><a href="{{store direct_url="privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode"}}">Privacy Policy</a></li>
</ul>
```

but when i remove this code then nothing is happening in frontend means the links are showing there after removing this code. i have flush my cache but nothing  happening.

Here is the code inside my page.xml file:

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Footer</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
            </block>
```

Comment: remove var/cache folder manually

Comment: is it safe to remove that folder manualy?? i'm a newbie to magento.

Comment: yes.. its safe. There magento keeps all cache datas. Dont need to be afraid. Feel free to remove it

Comment: ok i have removed my cache folder from root directory/var/cache/mage-1 and so on. but still nothing happened..:(

Comment: are you sure about the theme that you are using ?

Comment: Yes i'm using b-responsive theme with enterprise package enabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17940/discussion-between-manindra-singh-and-programmer-rkt).

Answer (score 1):

Check in `page.xml` (or `local.xml` if the theme only uses this) for the following:-

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml">
    <action method="setTitle"><title>Quick Links</title></action>
</block>
```

The layouts may be controlling the footer link blocks in the footer.

Comment: i have updated my question with page.xml code please check.

Comment: You have to specifically look for the blocks for each of the footer_links. Like my example above. If you disable the static block and the links still show in the frontend (disable cache first) then it is being rendered from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Developer
Change 'Current Configuration Scope:' to your frontend website (you'll find this in top-left corner of the page)

In Debug section, select yes in "Template Path Hints" and "Add Block Names to Hints".
Now, refresh the frontend page!
You will see each blocks location printed in red in your frontend website.
Check the footer block it's loading, then disable it or change the code from backend.